# Associated Account?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

[image: Account]

Does anyone know what this notification means?  Or why I got an extra 100 rep?

Answer (score 1):

See this post:

### [New Automatic Account Association](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-automatic-account-association/)

Comment: So, everyone got free 100 rep?

Comment: Well, actually, @Gnome, did you actually dissociate your accounts at some point in time? Because if not, this *may* be a sign of a certain oft-requested feature being implemented.

Comment: @Grace I switched from an OpenID to using my Google account a while back...but it was a *while* back.

Comment: @Gnome everyone active in one site gets 100 rep in all others, that's why you can see a lot of 101-rep users here on gaming.

Comment: @Oak  Aha.  I just associated my account with Programmers S.E. yesterday.  Would that do it?

Comment: @Gnome Not in this direction. There's something fishy going on, I'm investigating. Suffice to say, you appear to have gotten your bonus on Gaming... by associating it *with your Gaming account*. So... yeah...

Comment: @Grace if I haven't earned the rep bonus, I'll be happy to relinquish it.

Comment: @Gnome You qualify for it: your Meta Stack Overflow account has >200. I just don't know why it says you got it from Gaming. And, I don't think you've played with your associations there, either.

Comment: @Grace I'm getting it on Meta SO too: "You've associated your Meta Stack Overflow and Gaming accounts: +100 reputation"

Comment: [I just got it on Cooking SE as well](http://i.imgur.com/BGAfL.png)

Comment: @Gnome Both of those are expected. You've had your Gaming account at >200 for longer - it's getting the 200 elsewhere to get the bonus on Gaming that's separate.

Comment: @Grace could it be that there's another anonymous account on Gaming  with Gnome's OpenID that has now reached 200 reputation?

Answer (score 1):

I believe they did this because rep is a measure of **How well you know the site** this means that if you are good enough to get 200(+) rep on another site then, because all sites work basically identically you *should* know how to use all the other sites as well  .